# how to update subarray elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to update nested array elements in javascript. want to convert dates into different format. how i can updates nested elements

```
array1 = [
{
"week": [
"2019-05-06T16:00:00.000Z",
"2019-05-07T16:00:00.000Z",
"2019-05-08T16:00:00.000Z",
"2019-05-09T16:00:00.000Z",
"2019-05-10T16:00:00.000Z",
"2019-05-11T16:00:00.000Z",
"2019-05-12T16:00:00.000Z"
],
"weekNumber": 19
},
{
"week": [
"2019-05-20T16:00:00.000Z",
"2019-05-21T16:00:00.000Z",
"2019-05-22T16:00:00.000Z",
"2019-05-23T16:00:00.000Z",
"2019-05-24T16:00:00.000Z",
"2019-05-25T16:00:00.000Z",
"2019-05-26T16:00:00.000Z"
],
"weekNumber": 21
},
{
"week": [
"2019-06-03T16:00:00.000Z",
"2019-06-04T16:00:00.000Z",
"2019-06-05T16:00:00.000Z",
"2019-06-06T16:00:00.000Z",
"2019-06-07T16:00:00.000Z",
"2019-06-08T16:00:00.000Z",
"2019-06-09T16:00:00.000Z"
],
"weekNumber": 23
}
];

expectedResult = [
{
"week": [
"2019-05-06",
"2019-05-07",
"2019-05-08",
"2019-05-09",
"2019-05-10",
"2019-05-11",
"2019-05-12"
],
"weekNumber": 19
},
{
"week": [
"2019-05-20",
"2019-05-21",
"2019-05-22",
"2019-05-23",
"2019-05-24",
"2019-05-25",
"2019-05-26"
],
"weekNumber": 21
},
{
"week": [
"2019-06-03",
"2019-06-04",
"2019-06-05",
"2019-06-06",
"2019-06-07",
"2019-06-08",
"2019-06-09"
],
"weekNumber": 23
}
];
```

want to remove ":00:00.000Z" . I have format function which removed that but do not know how to call here

want to remove ":00:00.000Z" . I have format function which removed that but do not know how to call here

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` if you want a new array of can use `map` inside a `forEach`. Basically you need to use nested map.

This example shows use of two `map`, one nested inside another. In the nested map , the `week` is iterated and here the `Date` object is use. If you have a separate function you can call it inside nested map call back function like this

```
 let newfmt = array1.map(function(item) {
      return {
        week: item.week.map(function(elem) {
          // here elem will be each value inside the week array.
          // since map create an array here week will be an array of formatted dates
          return yourFunction(elem)
        }),
        weekNumber: item.weekNumber
      }
    })
```

```js
let array1 = [{
    "week": [
      "2019-05-06T16:00:00.000Z",
      "2019-05-07T16:00:00.000Z",
      "2019-05-08T16:00:00.000Z",
      "2019-05-09T16:00:00.000Z",
      "2019-05-10T16:00:00.000Z",
      "2019-05-11T16:00:00.000Z",
      "2019-05-12T16:00:00.000Z"
    ],
    "weekNumber": 19
  },
  {
    "week": [
      "2019-05-20T16:00:00.000Z",
      "2019-05-21T16:00:00.000Z",
      "2019-05-22T16:00:00.000Z",
      "2019-05-23T16:00:00.000Z",
      "2019-05-24T16:00:00.000Z",
      "2019-05-25T16:00:00.000Z",
      "2019-05-26T16:00:00.000Z"
    ],
    "weekNumber": 21
  },
  {
    "week": [
      "2019-06-03T16:00:00.000Z",
      "2019-06-04T16:00:00.000Z",
      "2019-06-05T16:00:00.000Z",
      "2019-06-06T16:00:00.000Z",
      "2019-06-07T16:00:00.000Z",
      "2019-06-08T16:00:00.000Z",
      "2019-06-09T16:00:00.000Z"
    ],
    "weekNumber": 23
  }
];

let newfmt = array1.map(function(item) {
  return {
    week: item.week.map(function(elem) {
      let dt = new Date(elem);
      return `${dt.getFullYear()}-${dt.getMonth()}-${dt.getDay()}`
    }),
    weekNumber: item.weekNumber
  }
})
   console.log(newfmt)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` and `split`

```js
let array1 = [{"week": ["2019-05-06T16:00:00.000Z","2019-05-07T16:00:00.000Z","2019-05-08T16:00:00.000Z","2019-05-09T16:00:00.000Z","2019-05-10T16:00:00.000Z","2019-05-11T16:00:00.000Z","2019-05-12T16:00:00.000Z"],"weekNumber": 19},
{"week": ["2019-05-20T16:00:00.000Z","2019-05-21T16:00:00.000Z","2019-05-22T16:00:00.000Z","2019-05-23T16:00:00.000Z","2019-05-24T16:00:00.000Z","2019-05-25T16:00:00.000Z","2019-05-26T16:00:00.000Z"],"weekNumber": 21},
{"week": ["2019-06-03T16:00:00.000Z","2019-06-04T16:00:00.000Z","2019-06-05T16:00:00.000Z","2019-06-06T16:00:00.000Z","2019-06-07T16:00:00.000Z","2019-06-08T16:00:00.000Z","2019-06-09T16:00:00.000Z"],"weekNumber": 23}];

let op = array1.map(e=>{
  e.week = e.week.map(val => val.split('T',1)[0])
  return e
})

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.assign for example:-

`const a = { x: "Hi", y: "Test" }
const b = Object.assign({}, a, { x: "Bye" });
console.log(b);`

Here rather then `x: "Bye"` you can iterate on week and do the formatting.

Comment: Yes, using map is a much better way.